# After Using HttpServletRequestWrapper I'm getting HttpMessageNotReadableException Required request body is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I'm trying to make an authorization mechanism in spring boot. Where I'm returning the PreAuthenticatedPrincipal as a body from the request. But after using the wrapper I'm getting a body not found error.

This is the authFilter

```
    public class AuthKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        CustomHttpRequestBody wrappedRequest = new CustomHttpRequestBody((HttpServletRequest) request);
        return new String(wrappedRequest.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

This is the Custom Wrapper

```
@Getter
public class CustomHttpRequestBody extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final String body;

    public CustomHttpRequestBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        super(request);
        InputStream requestInputStream = request.getInputStream();
        body = new String(StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(requestInputStream));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());

        ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                return byteArrayInputStream.available() == 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        return servletInputStream;
    }
}
```

This is the securityconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServiceHandler authorizationServiceHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        AuthKeyAuthFilter filter = new AuthKeyAuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
                if (null == principal || !authorizationServiceHandler.verify(principal))
                {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Authorization Error, refer to Documentation");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }
        });
        httpSecurity.
                antMatcher("/api/**").
                csrf().disable().
                sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
                and().addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

Quick help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You are reading the request and a request can be read only once. Your wrapper is effectively useless as that is only available in your method, instead your `doFilter` method should wrap it and then pass the wrapped request along.

Comment: Is there anyway to use request body to authenticate,?

Comment: As stated properly wrap the request and pass along the wrapped request.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get you, can you show me how to do an auth check on payload, assuming all calls are post with body.

Comment: You are already doing that, but your wrapping is wrong. You wrap the request and then call `filter.doChain(wrappedRequest, response)` else the wrapping is useless. So you need to do some more work. You can do the wrapping either in a different specialized filter or override the `doFilter` method, wrap it and call `super.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response, filterChain)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was a good catch, thanks much!